# Kendo UI: grid: conditional style based on compare of the values in 3rd and 4th cells, for each row

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, html-table, css-selectors, each

I am not sure how to pluck out the value in the 3rd and 4th cells (TD) to compare them.  If they have the same value, I want to add a cssClass to the row; not sure how to do that either:

```
 $("#grid tr").each(function() {


           var theValueInCell3 = ?   // how to get the cell's value?
           var theValueInCell4 = ?   // how to get the cell's value

           if (theValueInCell3 == theValueInCell4)
             {

                  //pseudo-code to add a cssClass to the row
                  $(this).addClass('foo');
             }

    });
```

EDIT: Here is my latest attempt trying to follow @Pechka's suggestion:

```
   .
   .
   .
   if (grid != null) {
    grid.dataSource.data(parsedData);        
    setTimeout(StyleRows, 500);
  }


  function StyleRows() {

      var grid = $('#grid').data('kendoGrid');
      $("#grid tr").each(function () { 
         var dataItem = grid.dataItem(this);   // dataItem is undefined
         if (dataItem.PropA == dataItem.PropB) {
            $(this).addClass('foo');
        }

    });
   }
```

The error is that `dataItem` is undefined.

Comment: `dataItem` is defined if you use a `DataSource` for initializing the `grid` but it seems from your code/comments that you are initializing the grid from an HTML table.

Comment: I am using a bona-fide kendo dataSource. Data are fetched from the server with XHR.

Comment: Umm! @Pechka solution should work. Check it in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/C25Aj/4/). Press button to run the code that changes the format.

Comment: @Emiliano Bartolome: thanks for your continuing to help me solve this. The only other "wrinkle" in my app is that the dataSource is initialized at configuration time to an empty array: `$("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
        data: [ ] ,
        schema: { ...`, and later on it gets new data :  `if (grid != null) {
        grid.dataSource.data(parsedData);        
        setTimeout(StyleRows, 500);
    }`;  I will try to put together a simple jsFiddle project to test that out scenario later today. StyleRows() is where the dataItem is being referenced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `KendoGrid` you probably have a [`DataSource`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#datasource-kendodatadatasource--object) bound to it. So each column have actually a name and you can get the value from the bound value.

If you prefer to go to jQuery path (as it seems from your draft code) you might take a look into [`nth-child`](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) selector that allows you to get the reference to *nth* cell or a table row.

```
$("tr", "#grid").each(function (idx, elem) {
    var theValueInCell3 = $(":nth-child(3)", elem).html();
    var theValueInCell4 = $(":nth-child(4)", elem).html();

    //pseudo-code to add a cssClass to the row
    if (theValueInCell3 === theValueInCell4) {
        $(this).addClass('foo');
    }
});
```

Finally for formatting a `KendoGrid` row, you might take a look into [Grid Row Template](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#rowtemplate-function).

Comment: thanks for the reply. If I iterate the dataSource instead of the html table, I can compare the values easily, but how would I get a handle to the table row the data occupy, in order to assign cssClass 'foo' to the table row? I have been trying n-th child selector, and can retrieve the cell, but I am having no success getting the value.

Comment: Did you try my proposed code? With `html()` you get the content of the cell. I have personally tried that code with an HTML defined table (decorated using `kendoGrid` and it worked). Check it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/u65nx/1/)

Comment: I do not understand these selectors `$("tr", "#grid")` and `$(":nth-child(3)", elem)`; so I must study some more jquery to understand what you are doing there. All of the `.each()` examples I found showed the `("#grid tr")`, not reversed as you have it. And they had `td:nth-child(3)`.

Comment: OK, I see, just AND'ing the selectors. I will try it

Comment: Here's the contents of the variable (as shown in the Immediate Window of Visual Studio) when I use your approach: `?theValueInCell3
"<A class=k-link href="http://localhost:50863/Schedule.htm#">out</A>"
    toJSON: function(){return this.valueOf()}
`. I want only the string "out".

Comment: Replace `html()` by `text()` (`$(":nth-child(3)", elem).text();`), I think that this might do the work.

Comment: Thanks. I spent some more time looking at the markup, and we need to add a third selector to avoid grabbing the column headers: `$("tr", ".k-grid-content", "#grid").each(...`. But so far I have not been able to get Pechka's `dataItem()` approach to work.

Comment: To avoid the header you might use `$("tr", grid.tbody).each(function (idx, elem) { ... })`.  Using `grid.tbody` (where `grid` is `$("#grid").data("kendoGrid");`) you only get the body of the table avoiding the extra selector.

Answer (score 5):

Hello I suggest you to use the [dataItem](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#dataitem) method which is used to retrieve the underlying model related to that row.
e.g.

```
var grid = $('#grid').data().kendoGrid;
$('#grid tr').each(function(){
     var dataItem = grid.dataItem(this);
     if(dataItem.PropName == dataItem.SomeOtherProp){
          $(this).addClass('foo');
     }
})
```

Comment: Could someone explain why the question was downvoted? The basis for this question is exactly analogous to RowFormatting event in the Telerik WinForms grid.  Conditional formatting based on cell values happens all the time, and it's just not clear to me how to get it down in Kendo.

Comment: dataItem is always `undefined`.  It may be a problem with the selector I am using to create the set for the `$(x).each()` iteration.

Comment: OK, problem was with selectors. dataItem now working too. Thank you. I've upvoted the answer.

Comment: it is also a different kettle of fish when grouping is in effect.  Would be nice to have a built-in function to get the dataItems which takes grouping/no grouping into account "behind-the-scenes".

Comment: When the grid is grouped, additional header and footer rows are created (even though I didn't see them when I checked the markup). To handle that, the selector must exclude the grouping, detail, and header rows:  `$(grid.tbody).find("> tr:not(.k-grouping-row, .k-detail-row, .k-group-footer)").each(...` otherwise `dataItem` can be `undefined`.